# iptables: recent module

Tags: iptables

I am using the "recent" module to prevent port scanning, such as:

```
-A INPUT -i eth0 -m recent --name PORTSCAN --update --seconds 60 -j DROP
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT         -m recent --name PORTSCAN --set -j DROP
```

The `--update` option, contrary to its name (i.e., update old value with new one), does not update the last-seen entry, but rather adds another one. In my simple setup, I am only interested in the last entry. I don't need the whole history of packets seen (i.e., for statistics).

Is there a way, I could only keep the last seen packet ? There used to be an option `--reap`, but AFAIK has been removed.

My concern is, that on a busy server, the PORTSCAN list could quickly grow pretty large. I don't know what the limit is, but I am sure there must be some limit.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you take a look at the man page for iptables specifically the `recent` modules section there are a couple of parameters that look like they'll give you the control you're looking for:

*excerpt from iptables `recent` module section*

> The module itself accepts parameters, defaults shown:
>
> ```
>    ip_list_tot=100
>           Number of addresses remembered per table.
>
>    ip_pkt_list_tot=20
>           Number of packets per address remembered.
> ```

So according to these two parameters you can control the number of IP addresses and the number packets that the `recent` module will "remember".

Remember this is a kernel module so to apply these settings you either need to set them at module load time like so:

```
/sbin/modprobe ipt_recent ip_list_tot=2000 ip_pkt_list_tot=255
```

On my Fedora 14 system the module is actually called `xt_recent`, you can see what types of parameters it can take using `modinfo`:

```
$ modinfo xt_recent
filename:       /lib/modules/2.6.35.14-106.fc14.x86_64/kernel/net/netfilter/xt_recent.ko
alias:          ip6t_recent
alias:          ipt_recent
license:        GPL
description:    Xtables: "recently-seen" host matching
author:         Jan Engelhardt <jengelh@medozas.de>
author:         Patrick McHardy <kaber@trash.net>
srcversion:     00B9A3AB999488BFEB4FA6A
depends:        
vermagic:       2.6.35.14-106.fc14.x86_64 SMP mod_unload 
parm:           ip_list_tot:number of IPs to remember per list (uint)
parm:           ip_pkt_list_tot:number of packets per IP address to remember (max. 255) (uint)
parm:           ip_list_hash_size:size of hash table used to look up IPs (uint)
parm:           ip_list_perms:permissions on /proc/net/xt_recent/* files (uint)
parm:           ip_list_uid:default owner of /proc/net/xt_recent/* files (uint)
parm:           ip_list_gid:default owning group of /proc/net/xt_recent/* files (uint)
```

#### Checking xt_recent settings

All the settings for this module are kept under the `/sys/module/xt_recent`. Specifically the parameters you pass into it are kept here:

```
$ ls -1 /sys/module/xt_recent/parameters/
ip_list_gid
ip_list_hash_size
ip_list_perms
ip_list_tot
ip_list_uid
ip_pkt_list_tot
```

Any of the parameters can be checked by simply cat'ing the files in this directory, for example:

```
cat /sys/module/xt_recent/parameters/ip_pkt_list_tot
```

So this tells us that the default value of for the parameter `ip_pkt_list_tot` is 20.

Comment: That works great. Thanks. I can now specify ip_pkt_list_tot=1 while loading the module. Regarding the other option, ip_list_tot, is there a way to find out what is the default/current value ?

Comment: OK, I see I can find the current values of the parameters in:  /sys/module/xt_recent/parameters/*

Comment: Sorry I stepped out, just saw your question, yes you can see everything under /sys/module/xt_recent/*. I'll update the answer with this info as well.

Comment: A nicer way to list the information in those files: `head /sys/module/xt_recent/parameters/*`

Comment: Great answer, wish the kernel settings interrogation information could get added to the man page for this module.

Comment: It appears that as of kernel version 4.0, an `ip_pkt_list_tot` value of '0' (the new default) no longer enforces an arbitrary limit, but instead defers to the value of `hit_count` when checking for a match (with an overall max of 255). Was not able to find this behavior documented outside of the source. See: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.0-rc1/source/net/netfilter/xt_recent.c#L63

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer given above, I suggest you stuff an additional BADGUYS table before your PORTSCAN trap, and use it to prevent spilling over the latter.

Then, when the PORTSCAN is triggered, add a record to the BADGUYS table.

Something like this:

```
-A INPUT --name PORTSCAN --rcheck --seconds 60 --reap --hits 20 -j set_bad
-A INPUT --name BADGUYS --rcheck --seconds 3600 --reap -j noway
-A INPUT <trap case> --name PORTSCAN --set
-A set_bad --name BADGUYS --set
-A noway -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
-A noway -j DROP
```